# Save multiple listbox values into a single text file

Tags: delphi

I make a small project in Delphi but I am having a problem saving the items of multiple listbox controls to a single file.

I have 4 listbox controls. The code for save button is:

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
    SaveDialog1.InitialDir := 'C:\MyProjects';

  ListBox1.Items.SaveToFile(SaveDialog1.FileName + '.txt');
end;
```

This is a picture of the project:

[image]

my ini file after save look like this

```
    $       22/01/2019
25/01/2019
21/01/2019
$       22/01/2019
18/01/2019
06/01/2019
       15/01/2019
31/12/2018
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how can i save the 4 listbox items in a single file?  thanks a lot

Comment: Ask that in the question by editing it. You'll need to decide on how the data is structured. If you just write the text alone then you won't be able to identify which strings belong to which lists. So, use a structured format, for instance JSON

Comment: Well first, you won't be able to directly use `SaveToFile()` like you are doing. Second, you'll need to decide how to separate each of these lists inside this file. Finally, you'll need to write the code to do so.

Comment: Mr Jerry Dodge how can i do this and can you give me the right code PLEASE

Comment: We aren't a code writing service. That's not what SO is for. Please visit the [help].

Comment: There are three bugs in your code: (1) The initial dir should be set before the dialog is shown, not after. (2) If the user closes the Save dialog without saving (e.g., by pressing Cancel or simply closing the dialog window), the save operation should be aborted. (3) The `FileName` property contains the extension (like `.txt`).

Comment: Abessi: Even if StackOverflow were a free code writing service, we couldn't help you since we don't know how you want the text file to look. Do you want all rows from the first list box immediately followed by the rows from the second and so on, or do you want a blank line between the four "sections", or do you want headers, or do you want to let each line in the output be the concatenation of the corresponding lines in each list box control? There are so many possibilities. We cannot guess what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

The `SaveToFile()` and `LoadFromFile()` methods of `TListBox.Items` do not support what you are looking for. `SaveToFile()` overwrites an existing file, and `LoadFromFile()` loads an entire file as-is, so there is no possibility of storing multiple ListBoxes to a single file with them.

You will have to get more involved in handling the file I/O in your own code. Which means, you have to first decide which format you want the file to be in, and only then can you code for that format.  What is most important is that the structure of the file needs to allow you to differentiate which strings belong to which ListBox.

For instance, you can use a format like INI, XML, JSON, etc, of which there are plenty of useful classes available to work with them, both native to Delphi itself, as well as 3rd party. And there are plenty of documentation and tutorials floating around for them all, so I will omit code examples of them here.

For example:

INI

```ini
[ListBox1]
Count=...
Item1=...
Item2=...
Item3=...

[ListBox2]
Count=...
Item1=...
Item2=...
Item3=...

[ListBox3]
Count=...
Item1=...
Item2=...
Item3=...

[ListBox4]
Count=...
Item1=...
Item2=...
Item3=...
```

XML

```xml
<lists>
  <list name="ListBox1">
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
  </list>
  <list name="ListBox2">
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
  </list>
  <list name="ListBox3">
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
  </list>
  <list name="ListBox4">
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
    <item>...</item>
  </list>
</lists>
```

JSON

```json
{
  "ListBox1": [
    "...",
    "...",
    "..."
  ],
  "ListBox2": [
    "...",
    "...",
    "..."
  ],
  "ListBox3": [
    "...",
    "...",
    "..."
  ],
  "ListBox4": [
    "...",
    "...",
    "..."
  ]
}
```

Just to name a few.

Or, you can design your own custom file format to suit your particular needs. For example:

```
procedure TForm1.Button5Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  FS: TFileStream;
  procedure WriteItems(Items: TStrings);
  var
    MS: TMemoryStream;
    Size: Int64;
  begin
    MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      Items.SaveToStream(MS);
      Size := MS.Size;
      FS.WriteBuffer(Size, SizeOf(Size));
      FS.CopyFrom(MS, 0);
    finally
      MS.Free;
    end;
  end;
begin
  SaveDialog1.InitialDir := 'C:\MyProjects';
  if SaveDialog1.Execute then
  begin
    FS := TFileStream.Create(SaveDialog1.FileName, fmCreate);
    try
      WriteItems(ListBox1.Items);
      WriteItems(ListBox2.Items);
      WriteItems(ListBox3.Items);
      WriteItems(ListBox4.Items);
    finally
      FS.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks for help but i can't save all the 4 listbox items in ini file   how can i do this and thanks again

Comment: @AbessiSofiene why not? What does your INI code look like? What problems are you running into? You need to be more specific. Please edit your question and add those details.

Comment: @mr Remy Lebeau  my ini file look like this                                                $       22/01/2019
25/01/2019
21/01/2019
$       22/01/2019
18/01/2019
06/01/2019
       15/01/2019
31/12/2018

Comment: @AbessiSofiene that is not an INI format. And I asked you to provide the code you are using to write the file. You didn't do that. How do you expect people to help you when we can't see what you are doing?